# replace a string inside a specific tag

Tags: php, regex

I have a description field with user entering `{tag}This has to be replaced{/tag}`
I want to replace the text with another. For this I am using the following code:

```
<?php
    $find = "/[^{tag}](.*)[^{\/tag}]/";
    $string = '{tag}This has to be replaced {/tag}';
    echo preg_replace($find, 'new text',$string);
?>
```

But I am not getting desired result. Also, in output I only want: `new text` . I don't want like this: `{tag}New text{/tag}`

Apart from this, how can I get the text between these tags ?

Kindly guide me on this

Comment: try `'~{tag}.*?{tag}~'`

Comment: Do not use regex delimiters with constructor notation. And [this demo](https://ideone.com/BRHZkm).

Comment: @AvinashRaj your method worked for me. Can you please post it as an answer ? also, can you guide me on what i would need to do if I want to get the string between this tag `{tag}get this text{/tag}` ?

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew your's also worked for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a non-greedy regex..

```
$find = '~{tag}.*?{/tag}~';
echo preg_replace($find, 'new text',$string);
```

If the text between `tag` `/tag` contain newline characters then you must use DOTALL modifier.

```
$find = '~(?s){tag}.*?{/tag}~';
```

To get text between those tags, use capturing groups/.

```
$find = '~{tag}(.*?){/tag}~';
$out = preg_match($find, $str);
echo $out[1];
```

Comment: `$out[1]` is displaying 1. I want the text between them

Comment: try `print_r( $out[1]);`

Comment: `echo preg_match("/(?s){tag}(.*?){\/tag}/", $string, $output_array);` I tried this, but result is 1. In demo you showed me, it's working :(

Comment: pls do like in my code.. or `preg_match("/(?s){tag}(.*?){\/tag}/", $string, $output_array); echo $output_array[1];`

Comment: OMG! :D how could I miss it. Thanks a lot @Avinash. it worked like charm

Comment: We r happy to help u :D

Comment: @Ruchi `preg_match` should do an one time match for global matching, you must use `preg_match_all` func..

Comment: sorry my comment got deleted by mistake. thank you for your quick response. `preg_match_all` worked